# Set a constant high signal to low

Tags: vhdl, state-machines

I have a keypad circuit, when I press and hold a key, the signal "key_pressed" is always high, as long as I keep the key pressed, which is normal, when I leave it, it gets low again. But I don't want this signal to be constantly high, no matter how long I press the key, I would like to be detected as a single short press. In other means I should find a way to set this key_pressed to low after lets say 10ms. I'm doing everything in VHDL, no resistors capacitors... I also can't wait for a falling edge then it makes no sense, no key will be displayed on the LCD until the key is released which does not make sense.

Comment: Sounds like you need an edge detector. Assuming debouncing is already taken care of...

Comment: I can't wait for a falling edge...

Comment: See Spehro's answer. I'm not sure where I implied anything having to do with the falling edge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *rising* edge detector. This is done by generating a delayed input that is 1 clock cycle later than the actual input.

For example:

```
               ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____      
CLock      ___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \

               _______________________________
Input      ___/                               \____________________________________
                        _______________________________
Input_z    ____________/                               \___________________________ 

                 ^ You want to detect this point, where the signals are not the
                   same. Input has gone high, but because Input_z is delayed, it 
                   isn't high yet
```

The delayed input is generated as follows:

```
gen_input_z : process(clk,rst) 
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        Input_z <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        Input_z <= Input;
    end if;
end process
```

Now you want to detect your rising edge:

```
gen_edge_det : process(clk,rst) 
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        Edge_detect <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (Input = '1' and Input_z = '0') then
            Edge_detect <= '1';
        else 
            Edge_detect <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process
```

But now our edge detect is only one clock cycle:

```
               ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____      
CLock      ___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \

               _______________________________
Input      ___/                               \____________________________________
                        _______________________________
Input_z    ____________/                               \___________________________ 
                        ________
Edge_det   ____________/        \__________________________________________________
```

To modify that, add in a counter which only makes edge detect fall after a certain number of clock cycles:

```
-- Port Declarations
signal clk         : in std_logic;
signal rst         : in std_logic;
signal input       : in std_logic;

-- Signal declarations
signal input_z     : std_logic;
signal edge_detect : std_logic;
signal counter     : unsigned(31 downto 0); -- include numeric_std for this


gen_edge_det : process(clk,rst) 
begin
    if (rst = '1') then
        Edge_detect <= '0';
        counter     <= '0';
        input_z     <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        input_z <= input;
        if (Input = '1' and Input_z = '0') then
            Edge_detect <= '1';
            counter     <= (others => '0');
        elsif (counter < 2) then          -- we want an edge detect of 2 clock cycles 
            Edge_detect <= '1';
            counter     <= counter + "1"; -- declare counter as unsigned.
        else
            Edge_detect <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process
```

Now it's doing what we want:

```
               ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____     ____      
CLock      ___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \___/    \

               _______________________________
Input      ___/                               \____________________________________
                        _______________________________
Input_z    ____________/                               \___________________________ 
                        _____________
Edge_det   ____________/             \_____________________________________________
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answering, there are 3 processes with the same name, I guess there is going to be 1 process with combination of 1 and 3 right? And finally `Edge_det` will be the output signal that I want right?

Comment: the three of the same names were just a typo, they're supposed to be different. yeah, 1 + 3 will do the trick. Edge_det is what you want.

Comment: I have an enable signal in the state machine which is 100Hz I switch between states every 100Hz so I will try to use that enable signal in my `gen_edge_det` but if I fail I will try to counter, how did you declare counter? signal `counter       : integer range 0 to 2 := 0;` ?

Comment: I'm getting this error "rising_edge can not have such operands in this context."

Comment: My clock is declared as bit maybe thats why.

Comment: Added signal declarations to 3rd process, included input_delay in 3rd process. This should clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 3):

The way I do this in firmware is to detect a change in the input (after rejecting noise and bounce) and then generate an event based on key press or an even based on key release for each key.

You can then use the key press and release events, in conjunction with timers to do all the usual functions you associate with keys on modern electronics. Hold the key for 3 seconds to get into a special mode, Hold the key, then release it to lock in an encoder setting or whatever.

Edit: Based on your changes, in the case of using VHDL (hardware) this can be accomplished with a clock and flip-flops. Simply compare the input X to a delayed version of the input X'. That will give you a one-clock pulse for the input rising edge (and, if you want it, a one-clock pulse for the input falling edge). It works just the same in an HDL as in sequential code.

Comment: The input will not change always High and the same key value. I edited my question a little.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're looking for a monostable multivibrator.  You can make them from a 555 timer, or use a dedicated chip.  For TTL, it's available as the 74xx123 component.  They work by detecting an edge and outputting a programmable duration pulse.  You can set the pulse parameters with external resistors and caps, if I remember correctly.  Pull up a datasheet.  They should contain example circuits for you to cut your teeth on.

Comment: 74ls121 works too.  If you don't have anything like that, I think you can make one with two invertors and an RC circuit.

Comment: Forgot to mention.  Since this is edge sensitive, no debouncing is necessary.  In fact, this device works as a debounce circuit on it's own.